# Can I use pricebooks for upgrades?

Tags: pricebook

I want to implement pricebooks in my application, and I have successfully set it up to generate net price promotions. However, I also offer product upgrades, for example - if buyer purchases Product A, they will get Product A Extra, which is a better version of product A. Is it possible to create price books for this case?
Tia.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not.  Upgrades should be treated as a separate SKU - hence a separate `Product2` record.  The price of the upgrade should have a standard list price.

However, you may need to think about these issues:

1. Special validation rules (done most likely in Apex) to prevent purchase of the upgrade if the Account hasn't previously purchased the base product. (Or, rely on the sales rep to do the right thing via training)
2. Upgrade pricing that is a % of the net price paid for the base product - that is, if the base product list price is $10 but was sold for $8 and the upgrade price is 25% of base, then you may need to use apex to calculate the offered price of the upgrade as 25% of $8 = $2.00 rather than show the offered price as 25% of $10 or $2.50